# FieldValue.increment is not a function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I tried for hours to update the users score stored in cloud firestore in my app using cloud functions but I am getting this error and I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

this is my code :

```
    const auth = require('firebase/auth');
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;

    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore();


exports.addPoints = functions.firestore
  .document(`users/{user}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

  const invitingFriendId = snap.data().invitingFriendId;
  const invitingFriendRef = db.collection('users').doc(invitingFriendId); 

  return invitingFriendRef.update("points", db.FieldValue.increment(50));
});
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, it's important to copy the text of it into the question so we can all see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to use the functions SDK to query Cloud Firestore.  That's not going to work at all.  The function SDK is just used for declare function triggers.  You need to use the Firebase Admin SDK to actually make the query when the function triggers.

Require firebase-admin in the most simple way:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

Then make the query with it:

```
admin.firestore().documet("...").update(...);
```

FieldValue increment can be referenced like this:

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment()
```

Comment: I am getting this error "db.collection(...).document is not a function" . I have updated my code in the question

Comment: I have solved the problem but I am now having this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined"

Comment: Can you show what changes you made to obtain this new error? I have been testing using this [tutorial](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-increment-tips/), and replicating that works fine.

Comment: FYI minor typo in the 2nd code block above: 'documet' should be 'document'

Answer (score 1):

I am writing for CloudCode too. It is good to understand that firestore variables do not necessarily point to the same thing as they are just names.

A. The firestore here is used to access the Firestore database and set the data. However, this firestore does not contain the FieldValue:

```
// The Firebase Admin SDK
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

//const firestore db, comes after initialize app
const firestore = admin.firestore()
```

B. Instead, FieldValue is contained, not in admin.firestore() which is the firestore above, but by the firestore object here:

```
const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue
```

C. Thus, completing the above, you can now use the two different firestore variables that we have, code B for getting the FieldValue and A for updating the database

```
// Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()

//const firestore, comes after initialize app
const firestore = admin.firestore()

const FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue

exports.createdLikesTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document(`likes/{uid}/posts-liked/{postId}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid
    const postId = context.params.postId
    const likeDocument = snap.data()
    const date = likeDocument.when
    const authorUid = likeDocument.author

    try{
        //increment post count
        const increment = FieldValue.increment(1);
        await firestore.collection('posts').doc(postId).update({likes: increment})
       
    catch(e){
        console.log("Error in incrementing likes: ", e)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error message, then managed to get this working with Firebase Functions after updating Firebase Functions to the latest version.

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set-up-node.js-and-the-firebase-cli

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same problem when trying to call decrement while updating a document in a firebase function.
Then I saw these two API docs

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.FieldValue

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue

Unlike firebase.firestore.FieldValue the admin version doesn't have increment/decrement methods. not sure why is that the case.
So instead I'm first reading the value using get() and then subtracting with an update().